# How to call handlePurchase() here? suspend function inside non-suspend

Tags: kotlin, in-app-purchase, kotlin-coroutines

just wondering if its possible to call suspend fun handlePurchase() inside:

```
suspend fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
    if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
            val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)


            val ackPurchaseResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val client = BillingClient.newBuilder(this@GoproActivity).build()
                client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams.build())
            }
        }
    }
}
private val purchasesUpdatedListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->

    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (purchase in purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase)  --->> here is the problem 
        }
    } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
    }
}
```

inside onCreate:

```
var billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases().build()


    val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
    skuList.add("dons.dogs.04")

    button.setOnClickListener {

        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {

            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                //                   TODO("Not yet implemented")
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    params.setSkusList(skuList)
                        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)

                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build()) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->

                        for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList!!) {
                            val flowPurchase = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                                .build()

                            val responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(
                                this@GoproActivity,
                                flowPurchase
                            ).responseCode
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
    }
```

Everything should be Ok after that. Until now purchases are happening but canceled/refunded because are not acknowledged. I tried to follow different tutorials and resources also the official documentation but dont understund how to implement this part here. As i said the "purchasing" part works properly but can not acknowledge them. Is there any easier way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `acknowledgePurchaseAsync` instead of `acknowledgePurchase` so you won't need to  make your function suspend. Also, use the same BillingClient instance that is already connected. You're creating a new instance for which you have not called `startConnection`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sir, i cant use the same billingClient because asks me to create a new val for that. Also acknowledgePurchaseAsync cant be called either. I just replaced as you said but just got errors. I'm doing something wrong bc i dont understund this very well. Just wanted to put some IAP but is a hell :S thanks for your help anyways

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " asks me to create a new val for that". You should have BillingClient in a property so your different functions can access it. Oh, and I agree, it is very convoluted. I had a hard time implementing it, even with 10+ years Android experience.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry, i should 've said that im just learning, and im struggling with some concepts, now i realize i should leave IAP for much later. Anyways i had billing client inside onCreate, thats why wasnt recognizing it, i put it outside onCreate and seems to work but cant use acknowledgePurchaseAsync, could you please be more specific on that? I mean how to implement it in that code if its possible. Atm im trying to do it but with no succes. Thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry, I remembered wrong. They have inconsistent naming in the library. For example, there is a `consume` suspend function and `consumeAsync` non-suspending function. But there are two `acknowledgePurchase` functions--one is async and the other is not. Use the one where you have to pass a listener, because that one doesn't suspend. Also, all of this code really needs to be in a ViewModel or a class what will outlive your Activity. Otherwise, the BillingClient session will be lost if the user rotates the screen.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sir, android studio tells me that there are 3 acknowledgePurchase, but all of them seems to recquire suspend. Im not getting it.

After .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken) is where i need to call  billingClient.acknowledgePurchase-> whatever? 

Is there where i need to pass the listener? my purchasesUpdatedListener doesnt seems to work either.

Is it really that hard to do this? Im getting frustrated xD  Thanks!

Comment: In AndroidStudio, I see 3 `acknowledgePurchase` functions, and only one of them is a suspend function. The other two have a second parameter that is a listener. Try calling `client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams.build()) {  /* log something here */ }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 hey! you are awesome. I did as you said and no errors on the code. Really appreciate. But now the app crashes when starting the activity where the purchsases happen. I checked logcat and seems to be crashing in:     .enablePendingPurchases().build() line, inside the purchasesUpdatedListener  "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference"  Any suggestion? xD For real you rock.

Comment: It could be many things. I can't really suggest anything without seeing the whole class. But as I mentioned before, I think you need to do this in a ViewModel. I'm not sure if it will crash if you do it in an Activity and the screen rotates.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks again, the whole app is supposed to be used only in vertical. I think the best i can do for that is just disable the horizontal rotation. But appreciate the tip.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I did solve it! If anyone's interested: after the "no null" problem, all you have to do is declare before onCreate  private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null  and then add "!!" after every billingClient and you are good to go. THANK YOU SO MUCH, sir. Couldnt do it without you. <3

Comment: Look up Kotlin “lateinit”. It’s a better solution than !!

Comment: @Tenfour04 Again... THANKS. You are right, i just declared billingClient as private lateinit var and removed all the "!!" and works as intended with no "null-pointer". Thank you very much for your time and knowledge, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
lifeCycleScope.launch{
     //your suspend function here
}
```